# OpenCV Picture stuck

Tags: python, opencv, queue

I am trying to make a small program with opencv. Basically it should show a picture to the user, then close it(or better let it open but this is another problem, because I don't now how to execute code, while letting the picture open) and then ask the user, what he just saw. For that I use imshow and waitKey. All works good but the picture doesn't close after a key is pressed. It stuck. I think its because after that command is another code to execute?

I think its because after that command is another code to execute?

import cv2

```
oriimg = cv2.imread('path')
img = cv2.resize(oriimg,(360,480))
solutionimg = "Answer"
cv2.imshow('Test', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
input("What can you see here?")


if input==solutionimg:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Right!")
else:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

`waitKey` doesn't close windows, it halts the program for the specified time. It is also a necessary step to display an image.
For your purposes, you can use `cv2.waitKey(1)`. This displays the image, and then prompts for input without having to press a key first. The image window will not close.

If you'd rather close the image before prompting, then you can use `cv2.destroyWindow([window_name])` to close a specific window.
 In your case that is  `cv2.destroyWindow('Test')`.

Documentation: [destroyWindow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga851ccdd6961022d1d5b4c4f255dbab34), [waitkey](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7)

Reviewing your code there are 2 more issues:
`cv2.imread('path')` 'path' need to be replaced with the image path. This is relative to the script, so if the image is in the same folder, then '[image_name].jpg' (or .png, ect) will suffice, but the full path always works.
You need to store the result of `input("What can you see here?")` in a variable. See the implementation in the sample code.

Sample code that works for me:

```
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    solutionimg = "Answer"
    cv2.imshow('Test', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    test = input("What can you see here?")

    if test == solutionimg:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            print("Right!")
    else:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            print("Wrong")
```

This code reads and shows an image. When you press a key it prompts  the use for input. Click in the terminal to input the answer. After pressing enter the image window closes and right / wrong is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, This works, but still the picture window freeze while waiting for the prompt. How can I solve this? It is reminding me a bit on errors I had with multithreads(process, queues etc.)... But I am not sure

Comment: I don't fully understand. What implementation have you tried?

Comment: The whole code is in the main post here. I just edited the "cv2.waitKey(1)". But after the picture window opens and the prompt appears, the window freeze till I write something in the prompt and the window gets closed with cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: In your question you mentioned keeping the window open, that is why I suggested `cv2.waitkey(1)` first. If you want the window to close automatically, you have to add `cv2.destroyWindow('Test')` after the waitkey. Also, `cv2.waitkey(1)` is not good in this situation, because the window will close after 1 millisecond. So either set it to 0, so the windows closes with a keypress, or set it to x milliseconds. For instance `cv2.waitkey(2000)` for a 2 second wait.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't close after 1 millisecond. It stuck. That probably happens because there is code to execute after the waitKey common? I am not sure, that's what I ask here. Also I want to close the picture only then, when someone typed something in the prompt. How is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean with 'stuck'? I've added a slightly modified version of your code to the answer, that works on my system. Can you test that?